# Sub query returning multi values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, sql-update

I have some null values in my table, I have to update that values from other table. I am using the following query but the sub query returns more than one value.

```
update student st 
set n_id=(select n_id 
          from class cl 
          where st.uid=cl.uid 
          and ( cl.start_date='31-jan-2011' or cl.start_date='28-feb-2011') 
          and st.n_id is null);
```

How can I update my field. Help me to find out. Thanks.

Comment: you need to ask yourself, why does the sub query return more than 1 value? if you are trying to set the row to a specific value, you obviously need just a single ( and correct ) value returned, so you need to look at what is currently returned and fix up your where clause to limit it to what you actually want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could either work on the logic or add the statement

```
and rownum = 1
```

then your subquery will always return just one row (the first one.. if it exists)

Comment: This is correct. __However__, @Samurai before using this approach think carefully and make sure that of all the values returned by that subquery, you really don't care which one gets used. If you _do_ care then you need to figure out which is the "correct" value and change your subquery to return only that one.